# Parse XML in Android from Prestashop webservice

Tags: android, xml, prestashop-1.5

Welcome everybody!
I'm new here and I looking for the solution of my problem with Prestashop webservice and Android.
I have to write an application for android, which parse XML from prestashop web service, and I don't know how to do it. Offcourse, I set up the webservice in the prestashop, which generate a xml. Finally, I have a xml:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  
   <api shop_name="myShop">
     <addresses xlink:href="https://myshop.pl/api/addresses" get="true" put="false" post="true" delete="false" head="true">
       <description xlink:href="https://myshop.pl/api/addresses" get="true" put="false" post="true" delete="false" head="true">The Customer, Manufacturer and Customer addresses</description>
       <schema xlink:href="https://myshop.pl/api/addresses?schema=blank" type="blank"/>
       <schema xlink:href="https://myshop.pl/api/addresses?schema=synopsis" type="synopsis"/>
     </addresses> 
   </api> 
</prestashop>
```

I try to use this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm) to parse the above xml, but is the problem `java.io.FileNotFoundException` in the line where is `InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream()`.

Does anyony Who can help me?

Sorry for my english, if there are any mistakes in the text.

Comment: Check the Conn first whether It is null or not ?

Comment: Can you access your service url from outside (e.g. in a browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, through adding this line before connect() method:

```
String userpassword = "key_authentication"+":"+""; // empty password should not be missed
String encoded = new String(Base64.encode(userpassword.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: If you only pass 'username' parameter and miss to pass empty password of PrestaShop API it will return 401 http error code which means Unauthorized. You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404778/prestashop-and-web-servicerestful-httpurlconnection-bufferedreader